# Varbinary(max) images Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, varbinary

I need to read records from a employee database and display selected items (not in Gridview) - this is fine except for the image that is stored in varbinary(max). I need to step through the records - forwards and backwards. There are some records that has not image.
I am having problems understanding the convertion method using that dataset for each record.

I am using visual studio 2008 and thryng to display the records in a windows form application.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is some of my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub GraduatesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GraduatesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.GraduatesBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Graduates_DatabaseDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Graduates_DatabaseDataSet.Graduates' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.GraduatesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Graduates_DatabaseDataSet.Graduates)
    End Sub

    Private Sub GraduatesBindingNavigator_RefreshItems(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GraduatesBindingNavigator.RefreshItems

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub PhotographLabel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub
    Private Sub SurnameTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SurnameTextBox.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub FillBysurnameToolStripButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try
            Me.GraduatesTableAdapter.FillBysurname(Me.Graduates_DatabaseDataSet.Graduates, SsnameToolStripTextBox.Text)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) and assign to its [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx) property an Image object created from the varbinary(max) field in your Graduates table, built using [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx).

Unfortunately there is no simple designer time binding you can use, you're going to have to hook an event to your databinding currency manager [PositionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingmanagerbase.positionchanged.aspx) event.